# Keep getting error code: no match for 'operator==' in 'Ltrl == r_string[i]'

Tags: c++

So I made this code to out print a randomized amount of characters from the alphabet, and to tell the location of a user selected pair of two characters from the list. My problem is I keep getting several errors that are telling me there are no "matches for the 'operator==' and such; I was hoping someone could tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix this.

Here is my code and a screen shot of the errors I am receiving. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsEie.png)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {

int n;
string Ltr1, Ltr2;
int i=0;
char alphabet[26];
char r_string[200];
srand(time(0));

cout << "How many letters do you want in your random string (no less than 0, no more than 100): ";
 cin >> n;

for (int i=0; i<=25; i++)
 alphabet[i] = 'a' + i;

while(i<n) {
    int temp = rand() % 26;
    r_string[i] = alphabet[temp];
    i++;
}

for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    cout<<r_string[i];
    cout<<"\n\n";

cout<<"\n\n What letter pair would you like to find? ";
cin>>Ltr1>>Ltr2;

 for (i=0; i<n; i++)
  if ((Ltr1 == r_string[i]) && (Ltr2 == r_string[i+1])) {
    cout<<" The pair is in the string starting at character number"<<i+1<<" in the string. \n";
}else{
    cout << "The letter pair "<< Ltr1, Ltr2 <<" is not in this string. \n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll bet you can remove almost all of that code and still get the error message. And once it's been removed, if the problem doesn't jump out at you, post the minimal code.

Comment: `Ltr1 == r_string[i]` you are trying to compare a std::string with a char and that operator is not defined, I beleive this is where you get the error?

Comment: Rough example of what Pete's talking about: https://ideone.com/8FqP2P

Comment: Oh okay, I will try and isolate the issue then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, operators (such as `==`, `!=`, `+`, and others) that involve non-pointer, [non-fundamental types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) have to be defined and implemented somewhere (there is also the issue of [implicitly convertible types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion), but that's beyond the scope of this question). For instance, take the following code:

```
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string my_str = "Hello world!", other_str = "Hello!";
    const char *my_c_str = "Hello world!", my_char = 'H';

    my_str == other_str;  //OK:  calls operator==(std::string, std::string)
    my_str[0] == my_char; //OK:  calls operator==(char, char)
    my_str == my_c_str;   //OK:  calls operator==(std::string, char*)
    my_str == my_char;    //bad: attempts to call operator==(std::string, char), which is not defined
}
```

In this case, you are trying to compare (with `operator==`) an `std::string` and a `char` - two types for which such an operator is not defined anywhere. The problem stems from the fact that a comparison between an `std::string` and a single `char` (*not* a c-string) is not defined by the standard library (or by you). This is, perhaps, because it is not immediately obvious how such a comparison would work.

If you want to compare the string and the c-string, you can simply compare the two using `my_str == my_c_str` - or, if you want to manually compare the individual characters, you may make each comparison in a similar manner (with each individual `char`).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
#include <string>
```

to the top of your code.

Comment: @Zethos this is a solution for a different problem you haven't encountered yet.